# Testing the OpenGL APIs

Tags: api, testing, opengl

I need to test whether the OpenGL API is working properly or not.
eg. glVertex3f(), glEnable(), etc...

Is there any test suite for testing the Opengl APIs

Is there any set of test cases ?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any set of test cases ?

Take a look at [`piglit`](http://people.freedesktop.org/~nh/piglit/) and/or [`glean`](http://glean.sourceforge.net/).

The official conformance suites are behind a rather steep [paywall](http://www.khronos.org/members/).

Comment: There is no conformance test suite for desktop GL. There used to be, but stopped being updated years ago.